# Reproducing the CPLEX Output

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, callback

I would like to reproduce the output of CPLEX, when it solves an MIP problem. That is, I would like to get the entries of the following example output, so that I can work with them.

I am especially interested in getting the branching variable (I suppose I can get the rest in a similar manner).

I would like to use the C API.

Can anyone help?

```
Node  Left    Objective   IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap         Variable B NodeID Parent  Depth
  1     3     3034.1684   588        0.0000     3034.1684     8562     ---            V5761 D      4      0      1
  3     4     3025.0305   674        0.0000     2993.5940     9283     ---            V5215 D      8      4      2
  4     5     2867.8075   542        0.0000     2993.5940    11893     ---            V5219 D      7      3      2
  8     8     2933.7516   649        0.0000     2976.2963    13510     ---            V5723 U     16     12      4
 13    12     2846.5455   528        0.0000     2976.2963    15227     ---            V7321 U     23     19      6
 18    10     2108.5714   522        0.0000     2976.2963    14249     ---            V7283 D     24     16      5
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can read the entries in the node log (number of nodes left, objective value etc.) into variables in a C program?

Comment: I don't want to read the file. I want to get the values that CPLEX is going to write in the file. Something like current_branching_variable = CPXgetCurrentBranchingVariable(). Suppose, the cplex routine for writing the output file has to be implemented by me.

Answer (score 3):

You can get at least some of the information at every node (not just at the nodes where CPLEX decides to print a log entry) by attaching an information callback. See `CPXsetinfocallbackfunc` in the docs for how to do that. In the callback, you can use `CPXgetcallbackinfo` to get things like node counts, iteration counts, incumbent objective value etc. (basically, scalar valued things) and `CPXgetcallbackincumbent` to get the current incumbent solution (if one exists).

To get the variable (or SOS) on which CPLEX is about to branch, you would need to attach a branch callback (`CPXsetbranchcallbackfunc`) and then decode the entries returned to figure out the variable(s) it chose. From there you can use `CPXbranchcallbackbranchasCPLEX` to tell CPLEX to go ahead with the branch (meaning you do not want to supply a different branching decision).

Comment: I followed your advise, but I get values different than those printed out by CPLEX. Could it be the case, that the callbacks return the values for the variables as they are numbered by cplex after preprocessing? If this is the case how could I translate them back to their original value (the value at input, before cplex manipulations)?

Comment: I don't use the C API, but as far as I know the variable`indices` uses the variable indexes as the problem was fed to CPLEX (before presolving). Are you saying that at a given iteration the callback is being told that the node count is 1 and `indices[0]` is $n$ while the output log is showing a pivot on a variable with index $m\neq n$?

Comment: Actually I think that the callback CPXsetbranchcallbackfunc tells me how many new nodes cplex is going to create and put them on the node list, not the variable cplex is going to actually branch on. I think this information I get by using the callback CPXgetcallbacknodeinfo but then this callback returns as the branching variable of the node being processed 2298, while cplex outputs variable V5761. If I were correct then I would expect the callback to return 5761.  I think I may misunderstand the description of the callbacks.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `CPXsetbranchcallbackfunc`, specifically the argument `indices` in the callback function you define. If that does not make sense, I suggest you try on the IBM CPLEX forum.